# Counting matches / Comparing two text files in python with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, utf-8, io

i'm trying to compare two files in utf-8, gold_standard_1.txt with 2553 lines and output_test1.txt with 2476 lines, both disordered, and count if a line in one file matches with another line in the other text file (not necessary same line numbers).

I have been trying many alternatives, like zip, intersections etc but does not work.

Samples:

gold_standard_1.txt:

```
En  Prep
total   Adj
,   Punt
los Det
organizadores   NC
de  Prep
la  Det
feria   NC
esperan V
en  Prep
La_Habana   NP
a   Prep
por_lo_menos    Adv
150 Num
editoriales NC
de  Prep
Europa  NP
,   Punt
América NP
y   Conj
Asia    NP
,   Punt
donde   Pron
por Prep
primera Adj
vez NC
concurrirán V
representantes  NC
de  Prep
Alemania    NP
y   Conj
Japón   NP
,   Punt
además_de   Prep
las Det
habituales  Adj
de  Prep
México  NP
,   Punt
Venezuela   NP
,   Punt
Argentina   NP
y   Conj
España  NP
,   Punt
según   Prep
dijo    V
el  Det
presidente  NC
del Prep
Instituto_Cubano_del_Libro  NP
,   Punt
Pablo_Pacheco   NP
.   Fin
Para    Prep
la  Det
comercialización    NC
la  Det
feria   NC
dispondrá   V
de  Prep
cerca_de    Prep
300.000 Num
ejemplares  Adj
de  Prep
México  NP
,   Punt
Santo_Domingo   NP
,   Punt
Ecuador NP
,   Punt
Venezuela   NP
,   Punt
Argentina   NP
,   Punt
Chile   NP
,   Punt
España_e_Inglaterra NP
.   Fin
Durante Prep
la  Det
feria   NC
se  Pron
desarrollará    V
un  Det
programa    NC
para    Prep
la  Det
lectura NC
de  Prep
textos  NC
,   Punt
tertulias   NC
,   Punt
encuentros  NC
de  Prep
escritores  NC
y   Conj
la  Det
presentación    NC
de  Prep
una Det
muestra V
especializada   Adj
dedicada    Adj
al  Prep
medio_ambiente  NC
y   Conj
la  Det
alimentación    NC
.   Fin
Entre   Prep
los Det
invitados   NC
figuran V
el  Det
director    NC
general Adj
del Prep
Centro_Regional_del_Libro_para_América_Latina   NP
y   Conj
el  Det
Caribe  NP
,   Punt
José_Salgar NP
,   Punt
la  Det
presidenta  NC
de  Prep
la  Det
Dirección_del_Libro_de_la_UNESCO    NP
,   Punt
Milagros_del_Corral NP
y   Conj
Alfredo_Weisflog    NP
,   Punt
quien   Pron
encabeza    V
el  Det
grupo   NC
interamericano  Adj
de  Prep
editores    NC
.   Fin
También Adv
ha  VAux
sido    V
anunciada   Adj
la  Det
presencia   NC
de  Prep
varios  Det
autores NC
latinoamericanos    Adj
como    Conj
los Det
argentinos  NC
Juan_Gelman NP
,   Punt
Adolfo_Colombé  NP
y   Conj
Norberto_Galusso    NP
,   Punt
la  Det
salvadoreña NC
Claribel_Alegría    NP
,   Punt
la  Det
chilena NC
Stela_Díaz_Varín    NP
y   Conj
el  Det
mexicano    NC
Eraclio_Zepeda  NP
.   Fin
Además  Adv
,   Punt
en  Prep
la  Det
feria   NC
serán   V
homenajeados    NC
los Det
escritores  NC
cubanos Adj
Dulce_María_Loynaz  NP
,   Punt
ganadora    Adj
del Prep
premio  NC
"   Punt
Cervantes   NC
"   Punt
de  Prep
literatura  NC
en  Prep
1992    Num
,   Punt
Eliseo_Diego    NP
,   Punt
premiado    Adj
con Prep
el  Det
galardón    NC
"   Punt
Juan_Rulfo  NP
"   Punt
1993    Num
,   Punt
y   Conj
el  Det
recién  Adv
fallecido   V
Severo_Sarduy   NP
.   Fin
La  Det
feria   NC
es  V
convocada   Adj
cada    Det
dos Det
años    NC
y   Conj
en  Prep
su  Det
programación    NC
incluye V
la  Pron
entrega V
del Prep
Premio_Nacional_de_Literatura   NP
y   Conj
el  Det
de  Prep
la  Det
Crítica NP
,   Punt
que Pron
proclama    NC
los Det
diez    NC
mejores Adj
títulos NC
publicados  Adj
el  Det
año NC
pasado  Adj
.   Fin
Los Det
cancilleres NC
de  Prep
Centroamérica   NP
y   Conj
la  Det
Comunidad_Económica_del_Caribe  NP
(   Fin
CARICOM NP
)   Fin
celebrarán  V
su  Det
tercera Adj
reunión NC
durante Prep
la  Det
primera Adj
semana  NC
de  Prep
marzo   NC
,   Punt
en  Prep
Costa_Rica  NP
,   Punt
para    Prep
analizar    V
asuntos NC
comunes Adj
a   Prep
ambas   Det
regiones    NC
y   Conj
la  Det
comercialización    NC
bananera    Adj
con Prep
la  Det
Unión_Europea   NP
(   Fin
UE  NP
)   Fin
.   Fin
El  Det
canciller   NC
costarricense   Adj
,   Punt
Bernd_Niehaus   NP
,   Punt
dijo    V
que Conj
en  Prep
esta    Det
reunión NC
continuará  V
el  Det
análisis    NC
conjunto    NC
de  Prep
diversas    Det
cuestiones  NC
,   Punt
como    Conj
en  Prep
las Det
dos Det
anteriores  Adj
reuniones   NC
,   Punt
celebradas  Adj
en  Prep
San_Pedro_Sula  NP
(   Fin
Honduras    NC
)   Fin
,   Punt
en  Prep
1992    Num
,   Punt
y   Conj
en  Prep
Kingston    NP
,   Punt
la  Det
capital NC
jamaicana   Adj
,   Punt
el  Det
año NC
pasado  Adj
.   Fin
Niehaus NP
consideró   V
que Conj
la  Det
comercialización    NC
bananera    Adj
no  Adv
estará  V
ausente Adj
de  Prep
esta    Det
reunión NC
,   Punt
por Prep
la  Det
importancia NC
que Pron
reviste V
para    Prep
la  Det
mayoría NC
de  Prep
naciones    NC
centroamericanas    Adj
y   Conj
caribeñas   Adj
,   Punt
muchas  Pron
de  Prep
las Det
cuales  Pron
dependen    V
en_gran_medida  Adv
de  Prep
la  Det
exportación NC
de  Prep
esta    Det
fruta   NC
.   Fin
Las Det
restricciones   NC
impuestas   Adj
por Prep
la  Det
UE  NP
a   Prep
la  Det
importación NC
de  Prep
esta    Det
fruta   NC
desde   Prep
julio   NC
pasado  Adj
y   Conj
que Pron
afectan V
a   Prep
América_Latina  NP
favorecen   V
a   Prep
varios  Pron
de  Prep
los Det
países  NC
del Prep
CARICOM NP
,   Punt
que Pron
fueron  V
colonias    NC
europeas    Adj
.   Fin
El  Det
canciller   NC
dijo    V
que Conj
se  Pron
debe    V
buscar  V
un  Det
acuerdo NC
sobre   Prep
comercialización    NC
del Prep
banano  NC
con Prep
la  Det
UE  NP
que Pron
no  Adv
afecte  V
a   Prep
la  Det
región  NC
caribeña    Adj
ni  Conj
a   Prep
los Det
productores NC
de  Prep
Latinoamérica   NP
,   Punt
quienes Pron
han VAux
visto   V
reducir V
sus Det
exportaciones   NC
de  Prep
la  Det
fruta   NC
de  Prep
2,5 Num
a   Prep
2   Num
millones    NC
de  Prep
toneladas   NC
por Prep
las Det
barreras    NC
europeas    Adj
.   Fin
Los Det
países  NC
productores Adj
de  Prep
café    NC
suave   Adj
de  Prep
América_Latina  NP
se  Pron
reunirán    V
mañana  NC
viernes NC
en  Prep
Guatemala   NP
para    Prep
analizar    V
los Det
primeros    Adj
resultados  NC
del Prep
plan    NC
de  Prep
retención   NC
y   Conj
el  Det
comportamiento  NC
de  Prep
las Det
exportaciones   NC
del Prep
grano   NC
en  Prep
el  Det
mercado NC
internacional   Adj
.   Fin
La  Det
Asociación_Nacional_de_Café NP
(   Fin
ANACAFE NP
)   Fin
de  Prep
Guatemala   NP
indicó  V
que Conj
la  Det
reunión NC
,   Punt
a   Prep
la  Det
que Pron
asistirán   V
Centroamérica   NP
y   Conj
Colombia    NP
,   Punt
servirá V
también Adv
para    Prep
analizar    V
el  Det
Convenio_Internacional_de_Café  NP
y   Conj
para    Prep
revisar V
los Det
avances NC
de  Prep
la  Det
creación    NC
de  Prep
la  Det
Asociación_de_Países_Productores_de_Café    NP
(   Fin
APC NP
)   Fin
.   Fin
Los Det
representantes  NC
evaluarán   V
el  Det
impacto NC
que Conj
ha  VAux
tenido  V
el  Det
plan    NC
de  Prep
retención   NC
en  Prep
el  Det
precio  NC
del Prep
grano   NC
,   Punt
que Pron
entró   V
en  Prep
vigor   NC
el  Det
1_de_octubre    Data
pasado  Adj
,   Punt
y   Conj
cómo    Pron
ha  VAux
afectado    V
a   Prep
la  Det
posición    NC
de  Prep
Brasil  NP
,   Punt
que Pron
aún Adv
no  Adv
lo  Pron
acepta  V
completamente   Adv
.   Fin
De  Prep
acuerdo NC
con Prep
ANACAFE NP
,   Punt
los Det
seis    Det
países  NC
han VAux
retenido    V
el  Det
20  Num
por Prep
ciento  NC
de  Prep
las Det
exportaciones   NC
,   Punt
lo  Det
que Pron
ha  VAux
permitido   V
que Conj
el  Det
quintal NC
(   Fin
de  Prep
50  Num
kilos   NC
)   Fin
,   Punt
puesto  NC
en  Prep
Nueva_York  NP
,   Punt
aumente V
de  Prep
60  Num
a   Prep
75  Num
dólares NC
.   Fin
Con_relación_al Prep
acuerdo NC
de  Prep
creación    NC
de  Prep
la  Det
asociación  NC
,   Punt
suscrito    Adj
en  Prep
septiembre  NC
pasado  Adj
en  Prep
Brasilia    NP
y   Conj
que Pron
representaría   V
a   Prep
más Adv
del Prep
50  Num
por Prep
ciento  NC
de  Prep
los Det
exportadores    NC
de  Prep
café    NC
a_nivel Adv
mundial Adj
,   Punt
los Det
países  NC
signatarios Adj
informarán  V
sobre   Prep
el  Det
procedimiento   NC
de  Prep
ratificación    NC
.   Fin
Resultados  NC
de  Prep
la  Det
novena  Adj
jornada NC
y   Conj
clasificaciones NC
de  Prep
los Det
Grupos_A    NP
y   Conj
B_de_la_Liga_Europea    NP
masculina   Adj
de  Prep
baloncesto  NC
:   Punt
-   Punt
Resultados  NC
:   Punt
--  Punt
Grupo_A NP
:   Punt
Barcelona   NP
(   Fin
ESP NP
)   Fin
77  Num
-   Punt
Benetton_Treviso    NP
(   Fin
ITA Adj
)   Fin
68  Num
Bayer_Leverkusen    NP
(   Fin
ALE NC
)   Fin
87  Num
-   Punt
Limoges NP
(   Fin
```

output_test1.txt

```
tertulias   NC
Según   unknown
tenido  V
Fiscalía_General    unknown
fuente  NC
PJ_PG_PP_PF_PC_PTOS NP
PJ_PG_PP_PF_PC_PTOS NP
magistrado  NC
magistrado  NC
invitados   NC
depositó    unknown
ciudad  NC
primer  Adj
YUG NP
pobreza NC
celebradas  Adj
según   unknown
a_pesar_de  Prep
viajar  V
suave   Adj
vez NC
quienes Pron
0   Num
masculina   Adj
encuentros  NC
solución    unknown
665 Num
negociación unknown
empresario  NC
feria   NC
feria   NC
feria   NC
feria   NC
feria   NC
seis    Det
cómo    unknown
alcanzando  V
estaba  V
región  unknown
718 Num
exportadores    NC
714 Num
711 Num
710 Num
BARCELONISTAS_SALVARON_DIFICIL_ESCOLLO  NP
ausente Adj
tratar  V
Benetton_Treviso    NP
francés unknown
imputadas   Adj
ilegales    Adj
dictó   unknown
--  Punt
--  Punt
--  Punt
reducir V
además_de   unknown
a_nivel Adv
afirmó  unknown
recabados   V
meses   NC
mundial Adj
peores  Adj
suscrito    V
pueblos NC
tenía   unknown
BEL NC
balneario   Adj
cuentas NC
cuentas NC
cuentas NC
señalaron   unknown
Pablo_Pacheco   NP
Grecia  NP
reviste V
abogado V
abogado V
comprado    V
importación unknown
sentencia   NC
sentencia   NC
Latinoamérica   unknown
Chiapas NP
Francia NP
Francia NP
Francia NP
Francia NP
Gaspar_Wittgren NP
escándalo   unknown
para_que    Conj
para_que    Conj
para_que    Conj
Butros_Gali NP
entrega V
sus Det
sus Det
sus Det
sus Det
sus Det
Caribe  Adj
capital NC
;   Punt
EP_Estambul-Panathinaikos_Cibona_Zagreb-Joventut_Benfica_Lisboa-Clear_Cantú_Pau_Orthez-Buckler_Bolonia  unknown
títulos unknown
Grupo_A NP
Grupo_A NP
reuniones   NC
77-68   Num
Brasilia    NP
Chipre  NP
Asociación_de_Países_Productores_de_Café    unknown
acuerdo NC
acuerdo NC
acuerdo NC
GRE NP
GRE NP
GRE NP
sucedía unknown
mes NC
mes NC
Thomas_K._Equels    NP
dedicada    Adj
norteamericanas Adj
viaje   NC
viaje   NC
Adolfo_Colombé  unknown
congelar    V
38  Num
Clark   NP
A_través_de unknown
30  Num
precio  NC
Policía_Federal unknown
barreras    NC
44  Num
44  Num
oficial Adj
acción  unknown
645 Num
incremento  NC
clima   NC
ING NP
julio   NC
importancia NC
apropió unknown
ONU_para_Chipre NP
Además  unknown
Stela_Díaz_Varín    unknown
unos    Pron
unos    Pron
semana  NC
semana  NC
2,5 Num
otros   Det
presidenta  NC
Ecuador NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
presidente  NC
Diez    Det
internacional   Adj
internacional   Adj
internacional   Adj
Europa  NP
Europa  NP
Bayer_Leverkusen    NP
Bayer_Leverkusen    NP
Instituto_Cubano_del_Libro  NP
espectadores    NC
activades   NC
conocer V
europeas    NC
europeas    NC
francesa    Adj
francesa    Adj
hacían  unknown
informarán  unknown
Iacopini    NP
6   Num
6   Num
6   Num
6   Num
6   Num
galardón    unknown
José_Salgar unknown
Unión_Europea   unknown
zona    NC
Pau_Orthez  NP
Pau_Orthez  NP
programación    unknown
Premio_Nacional_de_Literatura   NP
asistirá    unknown
mayoría unknown
sublevado   V
novena  Adj
novena  Adj
especialista    NC
servirá unknown
destacable  Adj
retención   unknown
Cervantes   NC
Vianini NP
94  Num
tribunal    NC
tribunal    NC
1993    Num
1992    Num
1992    Num
40  Num
40  Num
40  Num
autónomo    unknown
servido V
ALE NC
mi  Det
mi  Det
temas   NC
editoriales NC
Buckler_Bolonia NP
Buckler_Bolonia NP
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
del Prep
permita V
Colombia    NP
política    unknown
problemas   NC
tampoco Adv
vigor   NC
creación    unknown
558 Num
La  NP
La  NP
La  NP
La  NP
prisión unknown
financieras Adj
Comunidad_Económica_del_Caribe  unknown
propicio    Adj
mercado NC
Collor  NP
Collor  NP
Collor  NP
Collor  NP
Collor  NP
proceso NC
proceso NC
proceso NC
proceso NC
proceso NC
comercialización    unknown
lograr  V
Malinas NP
fuentes NC
fuentes NC
impacto NC
recién  unknown
representaría   unknown
Dirección_de_Recuperación_Patrimonial_de_la_Contraloría_General_de_la_Nación    unknown
Manuel_Antonio_Noriega  NP
ene NC
Yo  NP
asistirán   unknown
1   Num
presunta    Adj
Alemania    NP
acordadas   Adj
años    unknown
sin Prep
Bayer_Leverkusen-Barcelona_Benetton_Treviso-Racing_Malinas_Limoges-Guilford_Kings_Olympiakos-Real_Madrid    NP
iberoamericana  Adj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
y   Conj
4.850   Num
culpables   Adj
Gran_Bretaña    unknown
rechaza V
Destacó unknown
UE  NP
UE  NP
UE  NP
Pittis  NP
director    NC
sometido    V
hombre  NC
brasileño   unknown
especializada   Adj
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
las Det
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
a   Prep
trata   V
muertos Adj
canciller   NC
canciller   NC
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
su  Det
hasta   Prep
hasta   Prep
primera Adj
primera Adj
primera Adj
entró   unknown
logros  NC
Incidencias NC
686 Num
avances NC
680 Num
intercomunitarias   Adj
682 Num
También unknown
sucesor NC
Próxima unknown
connivencia NC
dimitió unknown
implantada  V
producen    V
Bernd_Niehaus   NP
España  unknown
mejores Adj
miembros    NC
Eraclio_Zepeda  NP
1_de_octubre    Data
ronda   NC
22  Num
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
la  Det
sospechosas Adj
lo  Pron
lo  Pron
lo  Pron
caribeña    unknown
fue V
fue V
fue V
fue V
fue V
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
,   Punt
```

As you can see, every line corresponds to: word+"\t"+tag

Here is my code:

```
with open("output_test1.txt", "r") as a, open("gold_standard_1.txt", "r") as b:

    dataA=a.readlines()
    dataB=b.readlines()
    aciertos = 0;
    for lineaA in dataA:
        lineaA.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')
        sintagmaA = lineaA.split('\t')
        for lineaB in dataB:
            lineaB.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')
            sintagmaB = lineaB.split('\t')
            print sintagmaB[0]
            print sintagmaA[0]
            if(sintagmaA[0] == sintagmaB[0] and sintagmaA[1]== sintagmaB[1]):
                aciertos+=1;
                break
```

And if I try to print aciertos, at the end, the value is always 0...but there are matches!!! How can I compare the documents in the right form?

Comment: `lineaA.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')` - this line is not doing what you think its doing, its effectively a no-op since you are not saving the results, the same for `lineaB.decode('latin_1').encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Ok, but with or without the (encode/decode) option, the program is not working...why?

Answer (score 1):

Your current technique is quite inefficient as you iterate over the second file *for each line* in the first.

Try the code below.

```
set_a, set_b = set(), set()
with open('a', 'r') as a, open('b', 'r') as b:
    for line in a:
        set_a.add(line)
    for l in b:
        set_b.add(line)

print set_a & set_b
```

What this does is builds two sets, each with lines from file `a` abd `b`. Then it does an intersection `set_a & set_b` to get the lines that are common to both files.

Replace `a` and `b` with your file names and do any additional encode / decode on the `line` in each for loop before adding it to the set. If not, the code will do an exact match of the lines (including leading / trailing whitespaces).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still not working :(, with your solution the program only detects 1 match, but must be > 100

Comment: You need to add the encode / decode part, and this only considers unique lines in the file, duplicates will be considered only once. Can you post both your files here http://pastie.org/ and share the links?